# systemd - does the `DynamicUser` option work with user units and if so, how?

Tags: systemd, documentation, systemd-unit

For systemd's system units (the units you operate with `systemctl --system` (default)), it's possible to specify `DynamicUser=yes` to make systemd dynamically allocate a user and group for the service to achieve some sense of sandboxing.

However while reading [the manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser=) I was not able to find any mention of if and how it works with user units (`systemctl --user`). So my questions are:

- Can `DynamicUser` be used in user units?
- If so, how exactly is it handled (i.e. what are the differences/quirks compared to using it in system units)?

Documentation from official/reputable sources is desirable, but I can understand if there is none. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not expect `DynamicUser` to work with user units (because your user account doesn't have the privileges to switch to another user), and even if it could, I'm not sure it makes sense for a "user unit" to be running as a different userid than the user that spawned it. In this case, why not just created a system unit?

Comment: @larsks yeah the "not having the privilege to switch users" bit makes sense. I'm packaging some software and simply wondering whether I should/could include `DynamicUser` in user units, since I failed to find explicit information on this in the manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with @Iarsks's comment in that `DynamicUser=yes` doesn't make much sense for a user unit.

Obviously, you wouldn't be able to create and switch users.  And if your unit needs to be a user-unit, then you wouldn't want this anyways.

So why do you want to add `DynamicUser=` to a `--user` unit?  An obvious answer could be "Because I've heard it's good for security".  In that case, consider what `DynamicUser=` does and choose the parts that make sense.

Here are two resources to help you decide that stuff:

- Feature explanation from the devs: http://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html
- `man systemd.exec`: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

`DynamicUser=` enables a lot of stuff that might make sense for the `--user` bus.  You could consider turning these on instead:

- `RemoveIPC=yes`. Careful, because when the unit stops, all IPC belonging to that user/group will be destroyed.  That might be a good thing, unless you have other services running on that `--user` bus.
- `NoNewPrivileges=yes` and `RestrictSUIDSGID=yes` prevent any scripts from taking advantage of password-less `sudo` configurations or capabilites.  Note that when running in user mode or in system mode without `User=`, setting `RestrictSUIDSGID=yes` will imply `NoNewPrivileges=yes`.
- `ProtectSystem=strict` and `ProtectHome=read-only` will prevent the service from writing to arbitrary file system locations.  If you want the service to be able to access something specific, specify those paths in `ReadWritePaths=`.  Or create temporary paths for this sort of thing with the next few options.  Note that `ProjectHome=` is only available to the user bus when unprivileged user namespaces are available.
- `PrivateTmp=yes`:  A private `/tmp` is created that other services cannot write to.  The temporary files are also cleaned up automatically.  This is only available to the user bus when unprivileged user namespaces are available.
- `RuntimeDirectory=`: Creates a writable runtime directory which is owned by the user/group and removed automatically when the unit is terminated.
- `StateDirectory=`, `CacheDirectory=` `LogsDirectory=` assign writable directories for these specific purposes.